# Number data type automatically loses precision in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, numbers, precision

```
private function getPercentage(max:Number, value:Number):int
{
   return Number((value*100) / max);
}
```

I call the above function to assign a percentage to an object.

```
var max:Number = findMax();
p.percentage = getPercentage(max, p.value);
```

Assume that p is some object with percentage defined as

```
public var percentage:Number;
```

When I put a breakpoint and check for the value returned in `getPercentage` it will something like 1.22343342322 but when I assign it to `p.percentage` it automatically becomes 1, losing the precision.

How do I handle this kind of a situation?

It says in the LiveDocs

> To store a floating-point number,
>   include a decimal point in the number.
>   If you omit a decimal point, the
>   number will be stored as an integer.

But how do I do that? Any insight to this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method `getPercentage()` returns `int`. Change it to `Number`.

Comment: Oh why didn't I see that :) Thanx!

Comment: I was waiting for the first 15 mins to pass :)